# BT Router and Assign Multiple IP Addresses

Tags: networking, router, tcpip

We have bt router model: BT2700HGV , 2wire, can someone tell me if this router supports this

Scenario is I have 2 webservers and want them to be available publicly , thanks

**update:**
A bit more information;

I attached pictures of my router system information, how did I assign the public IP to my router and to my Web Server. everything seems okay but I cant access to my web server from outside of my network. Firewall log says "Unknown inbound session stopped" as you can see in the picture.

[FirewallLog http://img412.imageshack.us/i/33374963.png/](http://img412.imageshack.us/i/33374963.png/) , [PublicIPOnRouter http://img704.imageshack.us/i/73894778.png/](http://img704.imageshack.us/i/73894778.png/) , [SystemInfo http://img704.imageshack.us/i/41567708.png/](http://img704.imageshack.us/i/41567708.png/) , [ClientIPSettings http://img85.imageshack.us/i/98347985.png/](http://img85.imageshack.us/i/98347985.png/)

http://img412.imageshack.us/i/33374963.png/ , 
http://img704.imageshack.us/i/73894778.png/ , 
http://img704.imageshack.us/i/41567708.png/ , 
http://img85.imageshack.us/i/98347985.png/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can configure port forwarding on that model. The problem you're going to have is that you can't port forward HTTP traffic from a single public ip address to two different internal ip addresses. The possible solutions are:

1. Obtain another ip address from your ISP.
2. Run both web sites on the same server and use host headers to differentiate the two.
3. Run one of the web sites on a port other than port 80.

Comment: i have 5 ip address already but dont know how to introduce them to my router

Comment: You'll probably need to look at the router's manual to see how to configure it to NAT multiple public ip addresses to multiple private ip addresses.

Comment: I put some more info about the situation. manual says, as long as I configure client manually (static IP), i dont need to deal with nat.

Comment: It looks like the traffic is getting to the router but the router is blocking it. Can you find a link to an online user guide for your model router? If so, I'll look through it and see if I can figure things out.

Comment: this is the manual, http://home.singtel.com/mio/2700HGV-User-Guide.pdf

also I came across this post on bt forum , http://btb.lithium.com/t5/Broadband-and-internet/trying-to-use-our-static-IPs-inside-our-BT-2700-HGV/m-p/4718#M929 it seems that everything is OK what im doing. i cant see what im missing. thanks

Comment: I'm not sure but I think maybe the Auto Firewall Open checkbox doesn't do what you think it does. Try looking at the firewall settings, referenced on pages 35-51 of the manual.

Comment: it worked if I change the server IP to dynamic first and assign a wan IP on the NAT section of the router, i can see it in the listed computers although it gets IP address from the other companies router which is on the different subnet. And changing it back to static IP did the trick. However now what happened is that one of this server is not displayed in the nat list now so again it doesnt work. is there any way i can force this server to use my own router?